# DNS change programmatically and keeping it that way

Tags: ios, iphone, dns

I have a `DNS` server and want my `iOS` device to always use that one instead. 
I am building an app that switches my `DNS` address on a button click.

Is it possible to do so in `iOS`?

My approach is:
User clicks on the button and the app backgrounds itself after a message.

Question:
Will the DNS remain changed if the app is backgrounded and not killed?

Comment: Is you device jail broken?  If not, then you can't affect DNS unless you are establishing a vpn connection

Comment: Do you have any resource that directs me on how to use my app in order to vpn to a server?